# robots.txt needs only certain files and folders and disallow everything

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt

I want **robots.txt** to allow only **index.php** and **images** folder and disallow all other folders, is this possible?

This is my code:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /index.php
Allow: /images
Disallow: /
```

Secondly, is it possible to do the same job with htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, be aware that the "Allow" option is actually a **non-standard** extension and is **not supported by all crawlers**. See the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#Allow_directive) (in the "Nonstandard extensions" section) and the [robotstxt.org page](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html).

> This is currently a bit awkward, as
>   **there is no "Allow" field**. The easy way is to put all files to be
>   disallowed into a separate directory, say "stuff", and leave the one
>   file in the level above this directory:

Some major crawlers *do* support it, but frustratingly they handle it in different ways. For example. Google prioritises Allow statements by matching characters and path length, whereas Bing prefers you to just put the Allow statements first. The example you've given above will work in both cases, though.

Bear in mind those crawlers who do not support it will simply ignore it, and will therefore just see your "Disallow" rule, effectively stopping them from indexing your entire site! You have to decide if the extra work moving files around (or writing a long list of Disallow rules for all your subdirectories) is really worth the bonus of getting indexed by the lesser crawlers. Probably not.

Ref htaccess, you can't really do anything useful with it here. You'd have to match the user agent against a large list of known bots and you'd just end up missing some - or worse, blocking real users.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that code is correct. The `robots.txt` file is read from top to bottom so as long as the `disallow` is on the bottom you won't run into problems. This is because it matches the first rule, if the `disallow` was on the top then it wouldn't ever reach the `allow` statements.

Edit/Sidenote:
This is only for "good" (Googlebot, Bingbot etc..) robots which follow the standard. Plenty of other robots either misinterpret the `robots.txt` file or just completely ignore it.